# Require at least one alpha character

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel

We have a login form that allows you to enter in your `user_id` or your `player_tag`. We have a model with the following rules:

```
protected $rules = ['player_tag' => 'required|unique|min:3|max:15|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/'];
```

Is there a way to add a rule that requires the `player_tag` field to contain at least 1 alpha character (`a-zA-Z`)?

Comment: So just to be clear you want it to contain at least one `a-zA-Z` but also allow `0-9`?

Comment: @MarkDavidson yes that is correct. So, `123` would be invalid but `a23` or `1b3` or `23sdf` would be valid

Comment: Makes sense. I've not tried it but could you add another regex rule something like `regex:/^.*[a-zA-Z].*$/'` preceding the current regex that should match then move onto your other regex for the final check.

Comment: Maybe someone can answer whether or not this is possible, I'm just checking out some questions: could OP use strpos() and require it to return a value? Although I suppose that's probably less efficient than straight regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help you:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/gD3gR6/2

Comment: Pro regex but you have an extra bracket

Comment: Why "might this help"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This will also match any characters that are non alphanumeric, when the intent (at least from what appears in the question) is to allow only underscores `_` aside from alphanumerics.

Comment: This looks like it is working the way I was looking for!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn have you taken into account Bogdan's warning that this answer allows many more characters than you specified in your original regex? See my answer for regexes allowing the same characters as your original one, but requiring one alpha character.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Strange, because in the working example you just added to the answer, if you [append an exclamation point](https://regex101.com/r/gD3gR6/3) `!` at the end of the string it gets matched, which is expected by how the regex is built.

Comment: That is what I am warning about. The regex in this answer will allow values like `pl@yer`, `playeЯ` or even `pl   ay   er` (note the spaces).

Answer (score 2):

If there should be one alpha character at the beginning of the field, you can simply extend your regex to check for one such char at the beginning:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
```

To require at least one alpha character without specific position, just use the following regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
```

Comment: Thank you, the second one is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
/^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

**Explanation :**

**1.** 0 or More digits;

**2.** At least 1 character; //this will ensure your at least one alpha condition

**3.** 0 or 1 alpha numeric characters;

Comment: Why should the OP "try this way"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.